# Not able to pinpoint css, that renders undesired padding

Tags: html, css, cellpadding

The folder tree has folder items represented by `ul` tag and file items by `li` tag. All of them are contained in a large `unordered list` container. All ul items are left padded by 40px but this setting, i am not sure where it picks from.

[image]

css box model as,

[image]

Computed rules have no mentioning about the padding properties,
[image]

Since i am not setting any padding related properties in any of the css files, how to debug this? Is there any debugging tool that shows from which css file, this padding space is rendered from?

Comment: Please post your code. Screenshots do not help a lot.

Comment: A `ul` has standard a `padding-left:40px;` to fix. select the the `ul` with css and add `padding:0px` or `padding-left:0px;`

Comment: @Vinc199789, you can make this as the answeer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `ul` has a standard `padding-left:40px` so in order to fix this the only thing is removing the `padding-left` of the `ul`items

```
ul{
   padding:0px;
}
```

or what also can

```
ul{
   padding-left:0px;
}
```